# Lowest possible value for k for triangle with an integer area

Tags: geometry, triangles

There is a triangle with sides length (9 + k), (39 + k), and (48 + k). The triangle has an area that is an integer. What is the smallest possible value for k?

I already tried pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Yes k is a positive integer. I know the answer, just not the way to do it.

Comment: It's easy enough with the computer...but the answer seems unenlightening.

Comment: @lulu I know it isn't an exciting problem, but I want to know a way to do it by hand. The answer is 52. However,  that is not the point.

Comment: Oh, I agree it's interesting (and I agree the answer is 52).  My point was that even possessing the answer, I couldn't see any other way to get at it.  Heron's formula is tempting...but I can't see any way to attack it abstractly.

Comment: @lulu Ah, I understand you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The semi-perimeter
$s = \frac12(96+3k)
= 48+3k/2
$.

Hero's formula states that,
if $A$ is the area,

$\begin{array}\\
A^2
&=s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)\\
&=(48+3k/2)(39+k/2)(9+k/2)(k/2)\\
&=k(96+3k)(78+k)(18+k)/16\\
&=3k(32+k)(78+k)(18+k)/16\\
\end{array}
$

Throwing this into Wolfy,
when $k=52$,
$A = 2730$.

Comment: Thanks I guess we shall accept this for now. Can't find a more intuitive way of solving it :)

Comment: I don't like it either, but that's math biz.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use Henon's formula. It states that if a triangle has sides $a, b, c$, then its area is given by
$$\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)},$$
where $s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$ is half the perimeter.

Comment: I know about Heron's formula. Unfortunately, how do I guarantee that the area is an integer? In other words what would I equal my huge square root to?